# Redirect auth controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Im using the Auth controller in Laravel along with the auth middleware.

If the user is not logged in it redirects to:

```
auth/login
```

But I wish to redirect to a different url.

I have this in my auth controller:

```
protected $loginPath = '/cms/login';
protected $redirectTo = '/cms';
```

But it still redirects to:

```
auth/login
```

How can I redirect the auth controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirection will be handled by middleware. Hence change the redirect under handle() method in auth middleware as follows:

```
    /**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->guest())
    {
        if ($request->ajax())
        {
            //return response('Unauthorized.', 401);

        }
        else
        {
            //return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
              return redirect()->guest('cms/login');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The path for the redirect when you're not logged in is handled in the authenticates middleware, which is found at `app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php`.